# How to configure a mail server on Debian Squeeze?

Tags: debian-squeeze, smtp, email-server

How can I configure a mail server on Debian Squeeze with Postfix or Exim4 without the need to relay on another smtp server?
And is it possible to add multiple email addresses for the same user? (Independant mailbox, not aliases)

I'm all new to mail server, Debian come with exim4, I can set it up to use tls etc... but I cant figure out how to make the server to send and receive mails without an external smtp server.

RoundCube is configured, but SMTP test always fail.

I've found this tutorial: http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/postfix.htm
And before I'm following it, is it good? I tried like 10 differents tutorials but it's always relying on a third party server.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Exim:

/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf

```
dc_smarthost='smtp.example.org'
```

Then run `sudo update-exim4.conf`

Comment: Um... does that not both "relay" and "rely" on another SMTP server?

Comment: Everything is on the same server (for now) and this is working... not sure what your comment is about sorry :S